# Usb Ethernet adaptor won't work. Mounted as storage

Tags: networking, 22.04, usb-modem

Already tried **unmounting**

Already tried **Usb modeswitch**

Already tried
modprobe **sr9700**

echo "efe6 9702" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/**sr9700**/new_id

Doesn't show on ifconfig

**inxi -nxxx output**:

Device: **usb Ethernet adaptor**
Type Usb; Driver Usb storage
Chipid 0fe6:9702 Classid 0806

Comment: Please see: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2484730 My recommendation is exactly the same here. "Return it and get one that is known to work."

Answer (score 1):

According to https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:0fe6-9702
'0fe6:9702' is a USB storage device, not an ethernet adapter.

Perhaps you have misidentified the device you are trying to activate.

To find the correct device, unplug your USB ethernet adapter from the usb and run the following (in a directory writable to you):

```
lsusb > current_devices.txt
```

Then reinsert the device and run

```
lsusb | diff -wu current_devices.txt -
```

(note trailing dash by itself) and see what new devices it shows.

Comment: What you see is a little storage device, part of the USB-to-ethernet dongle that contains Windows drivers. Windows, or in this case, usb_modeswitch, is supposed to bypass the storage part and activate the ethernet adapter. Unfortuneately, it doesn't work.

Comment: That was my second guess.  I was hoping that the diff would expose the real device along with the storage device.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same device here. It works with Windows, but not with Linux.
Thanks for that advice. Now: How can we tell vie USB to change the USB-Configuration to WiFi device?

Edit:

After trying lot of stuff from different www-pages I took a look at the USB-Descriptor:

The 0fe6:9702 is a multidevice. I has 2 child devices simultanously:

CDROM on Interface 0

and

USB to Ethernet Adapter on Interface 1

So you can't switch the config. You've to tell the driver to use Interface 1.

Who know how, please let us know. I'll use the rest of this weekend to try.